# How can I transfer data between screens but not switch screens in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a problem how to pass user data after logging in via the 'profile' screen BUT it is not switched to the profile screen?
I only know the code below is the data transfer is complete then the screen will switch? I searched a lot on the internet but there was none or maybe I don't know how to search for this keyword.

```
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', {
                  data: this.state.data
                });
```

Comment: use EventEmitter or Redux to dispatch data across screen

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Async Storage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) to access data after switching navigators.

Also, I'm not sure what's the problem with passing data with `navigation.navigate`. You can use `getParam()` to get data on the next screen.

### Update

Send data:

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', {
  nickName: 'MohamadKh75'
});
```

Get data in `Profile` screen:

```js
const name = this.props.navigation.getParam('nickName', 'defaultValue'); // name will be 'MohamadKh75'
const age = this.props.navigation.getParam('age', 123); // as we didn't pass 'age', the value is 123
```

Check [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/params) for more information!

Comment: I don't know how to send, how do I know how to receive it? But when you log into a commercial application the first thing you will be redirected to the home screen, how do you send the data to the user's profile?

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: Looks like I still don't understand what your answer means? What I want to ask is not the code you are coding there because the code I already know .... what I want to ask is how to send data across screens BUT NOT GO TO THAT SCREEN

Comment: Screens are meant to show data not to source them (I mean generally) - You may use global state managers like redux for that.

Comment: It's simple! take a look at [here](https://github.com/CharlesStover/reactn)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to switch screens but want to pass data across screens, first, since you don't want to switch screens, you don't need this:

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', {
     data: this.state.data
});
```

And instead, you need this:

```js
function_name() {
  // some code we will discuss below...
}
```

Second, since you want the data available across screens or more specifically send the data across screens but not go to that screens, you can use local storage like [Async Storage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install) (or [SQL lite](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) for big projects). That way, the data is available between screens, but not go to that screens.

For example, in Async Storage, you can store data in local but not switch screens:

```js
async storeData(key, value) {
   try {
     await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
   }
}


async button(key, value) {
  await this.storeData(key, value);
  // In case you like to switch screens anywhere you want,
  // you can uncomment the code below:
  // this.props.navigation.navigate('you screens')
}

render() {
  return(
    <Button onPress={() => this.button("data", this.state.data) } />
  );
}
```

Then, you can retrieve it anywhere you want on your screens, whether you want to switch screens or not:

```js
async getData(key) {
   try {
     const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
     if (value !== null) {
        return value;
     }
   }
}

async button(key) {
  const data = await this.getData(key);
 }

 render() {
   return(
      <Button onPress={() => this.button("data") } />
   );
}
```

Comment: I look very easy to understand but is it better than redux? I'm just starting to learn redux just to store global state managers....

Comment: Yes @khắc-thắng, I am assuming your are using **Expo**, you can visit this link [React Native Redux](https://github.com/Yasser-G/react-native-redux)

Comment: yeah! I made it very easy to do compared to redux ... Looks like I don't need to learn redux anymore. thank you